# Agrupar resultados en una sola fila sql server

Tags: sql-server

Vengo con una pequeña duda, estoy armando mi query para poder tener mi hora de entrada y salida en un sola fila en base a la fecha y el nombre de cada persona pero al momento de ejecutar el query como lo ingreso por separado debido a la validación que previamente me hace el biométrico de ingreso y salida , realizo un insert por las 2 condiciones pero al momento de mostrar el resultado me aparece como sale en la figura

```
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #DATOSCUENTA;
END 
SET LANGUAGE SPANISH; 
CREATE TABLE #DATOSCUENTA(
ID VARCHAR(10),
FECHA VARCHAR(12),
NOMBRE VARCHAR(100),
HORENT VARCHAR(5),
HORSAL VARCHAR(5),
HORALM VARCHAR(5),
DPTO VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO #DATOSCUENTA(FECHA,NOMBRE,ID,HORENT,DPTO)
SELECT        DISTINCT (format(ASIS_ING, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) AS FEC ,(NOMINA_APE+' '+NOMINA_NOM) AS NOMBRE, NOMINA_COD AS CEDULA,
CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'00:15',CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5),ASIS_HN,8)),0) AS TIME) AS HENTR,DEP_NOM
from dbo.GetRegistros 
WHERE (ASIS_ING >= '20/03/2023' AND ASIS_ING <= '26/03/2023' AND ASIS_TIPO = 'INGRESO' AND NOMINA_CAL1 = 'OBRERO')

ORDER BY NOMBRE

INSERT INTO #DATOSCUENTA(FECHA,NOMBRE,ID,HORSAL,DPTO)
SELECT        DISTINCT (format(ASIS_ING, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) AS FEC ,(NOMINA_APE+' '+NOMINA_NOM) AS NOMBRE, NOMINA_COD AS CEDULA, CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'00:15',CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5),ASIS_HN,8)),0) AS TIME)  AS HSALI,DEP_NOM
from dbo.GetRegistros 
WHERE (ASIS_ING >= '20/03/2023' AND ASIS_ING <= '26/03/2023' AND ASIS_TIPO = 'SALIDA' AND NOMINA_CAL1 = 'OBRERO')

ORDER BY NOMBRE

;WITH VISTA AS( SELECT
ID,NOMBRE,
(SELECT DISTINCT FECHA) AS FECHA,
(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL (CASE WHEN (HORENT>'0') THEN HORENT END,'00:00')) AS HORENT,
(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL (CASE WHEN (HORSAL>'0') THEN HORSAL END,'00:00')) AS HORSAL
,DPTO
FROM
    #DATOSCUENTA)
    
SELECT ID,NOMBRE,FECHA,HORENT,HORSAL,DPTO
FROM VISTA
ORDER BY NOMBRE
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que podría estar realizando erróneamente que causa se repita esa fila nuevamente, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: El problema principal que veo (si no he entendido mal lo que buscas) es que haces un SELECT DISTINCT sobre todas las columnas, y el DISTINCT te devuelve todas las filas en las que no coinciden los resultados de las columnas que seleccionas, por tanto, la hora de entrada y la de salida en este caso, siempre son diferentes y no coinciden con las demas, asi que la query te las muestra.

Comment: @Marc que tal buen día, le quite los `DISTINCT ` y sin embargo me arroja el mismo error :(

Comment: El problma no es el DISTINCT, yo entiendo por lo que dices que quieres obtener la ultima hora entrada y hora salida de una fecha o un rango, por tanto, el distinct debe estar alli, pero el problema que tienes es que la instruccion distinct mira los resultados de todas las columnas, y las horas de entrada y salida son siempre diferentes, por tanto, te las devuelve todas, si lo que quieres es obtener solo una linea deberias hacer un select MAX de las horas de entrada y salida y solamente obtener una linea del ID y Nombre y fecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estas haciendo un `DISTINCT` sobre todas las columnas, y las columnas de horas te devuelven siempre valores distintos, por lo que siempre te lo va a traer todo separado.

Para hacer lo que buscas debes aplicar un `GROUP BY` además de seleccionar el `MAX` de `HORAENT` y `HORASAL`.

Mas o menos la query deberia ser algo similar a esto:

```
SELECT ID,NOMBRE,FECHA,MAX(HORENT),MAX(HORSAL),DPTO
FROM VISTA 
GROUP BY ID,NOMBRE,FECHA,DPTO
ORDER BY NOMBRE
```

Puedes ver el código que he probado en el siguiente [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8e243/3).

En el ejemplo del Fiddle hago 4 inserts en la tabla `DATOSCUENTA`:

```
INSERT INTO DATOSCUENTA(ID,FECHA,NOMBRE,HORENT,HORSAL,DPTO)
VALUES ('123456789','24/03/2023','NOMBRE1', '00:00','16:30','CAMARA');
INSERT INTO DATOSCUENTA(ID,FECHA,NOMBRE,HORENT,HORSAL,DPTO)
VALUES ('123456789','24/03/2023','NOMBRE1', '09:00','00:00','CAMARA');
INSERT INTO DATOSCUENTA(ID,FECHA,NOMBRE,HORENT,HORSAL,DPTO)
VALUES ('123456789','23/03/2023','NOMBRE1', '00:00','17:30','CAMARA');
INSERT INTO DATOSCUENTA(ID,FECHA,NOMBRE,HORENT,HORSAL,DPTO)
VALUES ('123456789','23/03/2023','NOMBRE1', '08:00','00:00','CAMARA');
```

Para seleccionar solamente una linea por dia y persona se aplica un GROUP BY sobre esas columnas, obteniendo un resultado como este:

```
ID  NOMBRE  FECHA   HORENT  HORSAL  DPTO
123456789   NOMBRE1 23/03/2023  08:00   17:30   CAMARA
123456789   NOMBRE1 24/03/2023  09:00   16:30   CAMARA
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente ese pequeño detalle era la solución, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

en realidad solo necesitas **los primeros 2 insert** y luego un **select**.
Crea la tabla **#DatosCuentaIngreso** en el primer insert luego la tabla **#DatosCuentaSalida**.
Luego has el siguiente select.

```
Select *
from #DatosCuentaIngreso as i
Inner Join #DatosCuentaSalida as s on i.id = a.id and i.fecha = s.fecha and i.dpto = s.dpto.
```

Esto te entregara todo los registros de **#DatosCuentaIngreso** y todos los datos de **#DatosCuentaSalida** que existan el la tabla #DatosCuentaIngreso solamente; si por alguna razon no exiten los pares de registros ***Ingreso/Salida*** estos no seran  desplegados pero si los necesitas ver reemplaza el **"Inner Join" por "Left Outer Join"**.